# How can I return regular response in override get method, Django

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I try to use class based views in Django. And I have such problem: I define a base class for a blog (`BlogBaseView`) and two other classes, that inherit it. 
And in the second class(`BlogIndexView`) I want to make the search by get request, so I have override `get` method. It works, but if I don't make get request, it returns HttpResponse, however I want to return usual context (which `BlogIndexView` retunes without override `get` method).

What can I do?

```
class BlogBaseView(View):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(BlogBaseView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        blog_categories = []
        categories = BlogCategory.objects.all()
        for category in categories:
            blog_categories.append(tuple([category, category.get_number_of_category_items]))

        context['name_page'] = 'blog'
        context['tags'] = Tag.objects.all()
        context['blog_categories'] = blog_categories
        return context

class BlogIndexView(BlogBaseView, ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_create')
    template_name = 'index_blog.html'
    context_object_name  = 'posts'

    def get(self, request):
        if request.GET.get('tag'):
            context = {
                'posts' : Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[request.GET.get('tag')])
            }
            return render(request, self.template_name, context)
        return HttpResponse('result')

class BlogFullPostView(BlogBaseView, DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'full_post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_id'
    context_object_name = 'post'
```

Thanks!

Comment: Not sure what are you trying to do. Do you mean BlogIndexView should use the same context as BlogBaseView and add Post objects to the context?

Comment: No, BlogIndexView - shows all Posts in list, BlogFullPostView - shows one full post, and BlogBaseView pass the same context(for example side bar) for two inherited classes(BlogFullPostView and BlogIndexView)

Comment: Ok. Same answer still applies, if you really need to override the get method, make sure you call self.get_context_data, otherwise try out my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ListView` class also has a `get_context_data` method, so you should override that instead of `get` method. Using [`super`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/576169/understanding-python-super-with-init-methods) you'll get access to `BlogBaseView.get_context_data` and then you can extended the result.

Here's how:

```
class BlogIndexView(BlogBaseView, ListView):
    queryset = Post.objects.all().order_by('-date_create')
    template_name = 'index_blog.html'
    context_object_name  = 'posts'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        # use the (super) force Luke
        context = super(BlogIndexView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        if self.request.GET.get('tag'):
            context['posts'] = Post.objects.filter(tags__name__in=[self.request.GET.get('tag')])
        return context
```

Comment: But it cause error: `name 'request' is not defined`

Comment: Can I ask you something? What are the differences between method `get_context_data` and `get` method?

Comment: Sure! In short, the `get` method is called when a GET request is made to the view and returns an HttpResponse. What does the `get` method do? It depends if it's a ListView, DetailView, FormView, ... but they all call `get_context_data` to insert context into the template. Was that clear to you?

Answer (score 1):

If you are overriding `ListView` then it's not a good idea to override the `get` method, as you will lose a lot of the `ListView` functionality.

In this case, it would be a better idea to override `get_queryset`, and do the search there.

```
def get_queryset(self):
    queryset = super(BlogIndexView, self). get_queryset() 
    if request.GET.get('tag'):
        queryset = queryset.filter(tags__name=request.GET['tag'])
    return queryset
```